# Parsing PHP object value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following

```
Imgur\Api\Model\Basic Object
(
    [data:Imgur\Api\Model\Basic:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1XgbfFV
            [title] => PIC 2 TITLE
            [description] => PIC 2 DESC
            [datetime] => 1472495069
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [animated] => 
            [width] => 590
            [height] => 1382
            [size] => 35307
            [views] => 0
            [bandwidth] => 0
            [vote] => 
            [favorite] => 
            [nsfw] => 
            [section] => 
            [account_url] => 
            [account_id] => 0
            [in_gallery] => 
            [deletehash] => tZUGIGuV9Bfv6lV
            [name] => PIC 2 NAME
            [link] => http://i.imgur.com/1XgbfFV.jpg
            [is_ad] => 
        )

    [success:Imgur\Api\Model\Basic:private] => 1
    [status:Imgur\Api\Model\Basic:private] => 200
)
```

I trying get the [id] so I tried something like

```
$basic = $client->api('image')->upload($imageData);
$data = $basic->id;
print_r($data);
```

but value is empty. what should I do to get the value of [id] into $data

Thanks!

Comment: You can't get it that way because it's private.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, any ways for me to get the data?

Comment: Is this a class that you have created or one from a vendor package?

Comment: Have you checked the API reference to see if it offers any accessor methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All items in the data object are private.  What you should do is in your Imgur class, create a new method `getData` which returns the data object.

```
public function getData() 
{
    return $this->data;
}
```

You can also expand this further by creating a magic get method.

```
public function __get($property)
{
    if( isset($this->data[$property] ) {
        return $this->data[$property];
    }

    return null;
}
```

If doing it the magic method way, you can then just run, 
`$basic->id` and it should respond with `1XgbfFV` because of the magic getter.

If this is not a class that you have created, you will need to look at the API from Imgur package to determine if there is an accessor for the data array.

Answer (score 1):

If [this is the same code you're using in PHP](https://github.com/Adyg/php-imgur-api-client) to talk to the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/) then as [you can see from the code it has a `getData()` public method](https://github.com/Adyg/php-imgur-api-client/blob/master/lib/Imgur/Api/Model/Basic.php#L60) in `/lib/Imgur/Api/Model/Basic.php` on line `60`, which returns the private member. Because the member is private you can't access it directly from your `$basic` object, which appears to be an instance of `Imgur\Api\Model\Basic`.

So instead you use the public getter like this...

```
$basic = $client->api('image')->upload($imageData);
$data  = $basic->getData();
var_dump($data->id);
```